# How to get started? Simple text editor with C

Tags: c, textedit

I have to do a simple text editor using the c language. But I don't know how to get started. The program should begin with a blank screen, waiting for the user to write something. The user is also able to move the cursor using the arrow keys and the user is also able to load text files to the program from his hard drive and also make a text file of something the user has written in the program.
He can load something by pressing CTRL-O or he can press CTRL-S to save something followed by the name of the text file. 
 Our professor said that we have to use the library screenUtils to make the cursor move.
How should I start? I'm trying to make this work for 3 hours but nothing really works.

Comment: What platform? Are you using any kind of toolkit for windowing or anything?

Answer (score 3):

> Our professor said that we have to use the library screenUtils to make the cursor move. How should I start?

I would start by reading the documentation for this library.

Comment: I can find anything on the internet.

Comment: Didn't he supply you with documentation? If he gave you a download link, did you try looking around the website?